# Javascript - event.stopPropagation() not working from parent to child on BS4 accordion

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-accordion

I am using BS4 accordion with nesting each other.

I have faced event bubbling with parent to child and child to parent both I have solved one that is from child to parent using the event.stopPropagation() but event bubbling from parent to child is not stopped why?

Here is the code

```
$('.card > .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().find(".flaticon-down-arrow").removeClass("flaticon-down-arrow").addClass("flaticon-right-arrow");

  }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().find(".flaticon-right-arrow").removeClass("flaticon-right-arrow").addClass("flaticon-down-arrow");

})
```

[Here is my codepen link](https://codepen.io/owaiz/pen/wxNpVN?editors=1010)

**Note:** - *Inspect to the changes of classes*

Comment: Bubbling goes one direction, *up* the DOM tree.

Comment: maybe event capturing ??

Comment: You should explain your problem/desired behavior, instead of saying something that can't work doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event bubbling only goes up the DOM tree (from child to parent, to grandparent, etc). It does not go *down* the DOM tree. Thus, any event on the parent will never bubble to its children.

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture) states that during event bubbling (for a click event):

> The browser checks to see if the element that was actually clicked on has an onclick event handler registered on it in the bubbling phase, and runs it if so.
>   Then it moves on to the next immediate ancestor element and does the same thing, then the next one, and so on until it reaches the  element.